# Fullcalendar - prohibition of creating a long event

Tags: fullcalendar

I am creating a booking calendar using Fullcalendar and React js. There are two ways to create slots:

1. By clicking on an empty space, an event of a fixed length is created.
2. We start from scratch. By selecting the right mouse button, create an event with the desired length. (when moving the cursor, the event stretch animation is shown)

I need to create only fixed size slots. I want to disable the second method.

Pictures for understanding:

[image: method 1]

[image: method 2]

I have been looking for an answer on the Internet for a long time and have not yet found it.

Comment: You can implement your restriction via the [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) callback